# Spyder outline view of Python code: Save as text?

Tags: python, spyder

I quite like the Spyder IDE's outline view of my Python code, and would like to save it as text to aid in documentation. I could not find a way to do this and wondered:

- Is their a way I am missing?
- Or is their a separate tool that can give a similar hierarchical outline of a Python source file?
- Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, it is not possible to save our Outline tree view as text, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know of another tool with similar, but textual outlining functionality?

Comment: I don't, sorry.